# Sync a GitHub repo to BitBucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm very new to git and need to do some work with my colleagues on BitBucket, but we can't seem to push anything using SourceTree (due to some username/password errors, which we couldn't resolve no matter how much we tried).

We ended up using GitHub, but our teacher insists on us using BitBucket, which is a shame since we find GitHub much easier, and have already started working with it and setting everything up, and most importantly, we can make it work!

I saw this post about how to sync a BitBucket repo to GitHub, and I was wondering if it was possible to do the opposite, sync a GitHub repo to BitBucket, and for it to sync automatically.

https://medium.com/@dmitryshaposhnik/sync-bitbucket-repo-to-github-669458ea9a5e

I searched a lot and this was the only post in which it wasn't necessary to use the command prompt (which is what I wanted, since I just started working with git and don't really know how to use it, so using the pipelines from BitBucket was much easier).

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: You could not login to GitHub with username and password while pushing because it is not allowed. Use a Personal Access Token (PAT).

Comment: You can use repository mirror by installing this plugin https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211351/repository-mirror-plugin-for-bitbucket

Comment: @fredrik I couldn't login in BitBucket while using SourceTree, not GitHub

Comment: @Eng_Farghly I don't think I can use the plugin on a BitBucket repository, can I?